# Internet connection inconsistent

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, drivers

Recently, I have been having problems with my Internet connection. I am connected to the Internet, the connection is strong, but when I try to type in websites in the address bar other than Google and YouTube, the computer tells me that the page cannot be displayed even though I am connected.

I went to my *Troubleshooting* and after the computer performed a troubleshoot, it was unable to automatically fix the issues found that were, which I are listed below:

- ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.1) has a driver problem
- PCI Simple Communications Controller doesn't have a driver
- PCI Serial Port doesn't have a driver

It says that all of these problems are not fixed. I am not exactly sure what these things mean, but I'm thinking it has something to with communication between my Internet and connecting to webpages? I know there is nothing wrong with my Internet connection because my sister has the same computer as me and has quite a significant amount of problems on her system, but her Internet runs great.

I need help on getting those three problems fixed.

Comment: Open device manager. Anything with yellow exclamation marks? Also, try updating your drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the software located on this page, install it and reboot. http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/catalystlegacywin8.aspx

That will take care of your issue for your video card driver. If you post your computer model I can give you a link that you can follow to install the drivers for your NIC card to get you up and working.